# Get the current culture in a controller asp.net-core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

I have setup the cultures for my views and changing the culture in a controller but I can't seem to find how to know what culture I'm currently using in a controller, I'm looking for something like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
  {
      // Something like the next line
      var requestCulture = GetRequestedCulture()
      return View();
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you set (save) the selected culture? In the cookie or you are chaning the UICulture for the app domain?

Comment: In the cookie :) thanks!

Comment: I imagine that I could get the information stored on the cookies but I can't seem to find a way to do it. There's also the problem of what happens when the user has just entered the website for first time, there won't be any cookies on his system.

Comment: 6 years later and I still get points from this question

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The answer was on the Request Object, here's the code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    // Retrieves the requested culture
    var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    // Culture contains the information of the requested culture
    var culture = rqf.RequestCulture.Culture;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.IRequestCultureFeature: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization/

Comment: How is this different from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` ?

Comment: @Shikyo That doesn't exist in .NET Core from what I can see.

Comment: @NickG I double checked, it certainly does exist, what version are you using? I am on 2.2

Comment: I was using 3.1

Comment: @NickG you're wrong, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture exists in 3.1. I'm also using it.

Comment: @JohnnyAce confirmed on .NET 5 with request localization and **RouteDataRequestCultureProvider**. thank you very much, cheers.

Answer (score 21):

JohnnysAce answer works. If you just want an easy way to get the current culture, it is done as always in .net:

```
CultureInfo uiCultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

If you want to use *IRequestCultureFeature* (see JohnnyAces answer; because of dependency injection and better testability), you have to configure things in Startup.cs. Microsoft provided a sample here https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/2fcbabef58c2c21845848c35e9d5e5f89b19adc5/samples/Localization.StarterWeb/Startup.cs

Comment: Since ASP.NET Core doesn't have its own SynchronizationContext to do housekeeping, I do not think this works like in regular ASP.NET. If you never set the current culture, there is no problem of course.

Comment: This does seem to work after doing `app.UseRequestLocalization(options)`

Comment: That github link is dead by the way, fixed link: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/2fcbabef58c2c21845848c35e9d5e5f89b19adc5/samples/Localization.StarterWeb/Startup.cs

Comment: This won't work once you use a single async/await where you switch threads and you end up localizing the wrong request/thread.

Comment: @SeriousM: it works even if you switch threads through async/await, I have just tested it.

Comment: @RobertJ: using async/await does not guarantee that you will switch threads, it just states that you allow to switch threads if needed. Please check again.

Comment: @SeriousM The Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is used so widely  in classic  .net framework applications so the framework guys made it working . The async stuff is also part of .net framework (classic), and I remember it used to be a problem with exactly what you describe but MS decided to "fix" it with V4.6 (fix it is not the proper word since it is not a bug).

Comment: @yonexbat do you have a link to that "fix"? I would really love to read how they did it.

Comment: @SeriousM From MS WEb: Starting with apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6, the calling thread's culture is inherited by each task, even if the task runs asynchronously on a thread pool thread.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: @SeriousM If they didn't that would mean that string formatting would also be subject to the wrong culture - so they didn't really have a choice, this has to work.

Comment: i set it in middleware, and in IActionFilter (using Thread.CurrentThread...), both get lost when code reached the controller :|

Answer (score 20):

ASP.Net Core 3.1:

I can confirm that this is working if it's configured properly (see the second code block)

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

In your startup class add this to the `Configure` method:

```
            IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"), //English US
                new CultureInfo("ar-SY"), //Arabic SY
            };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"), //English US will be the default culture (for new visitors)
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Then the user can change the culture by calling this action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Path = Url.Content("~/") });

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: There is a problem with relying on the thread when using `async await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. There is a chance that after the await you are on a different thread than the one you started on. Not allowing `ConfigureAwait(false)` can in some cases lead to deadlocks. In that case you should get your culture before calling any `ConfigureAwait(false)` and pass it on to the view in the model.

Answer (score 5):

This code works for getting current culture in asp core controller:

```
public string GetCulture() => $"CurrentCulture:{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}, CurrentUICulture:{CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}";
```

Comment: This is much easier (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) since you can assign this to a global variable in constructor of controller and use it in whatever method you want inside the controller. While getting the culture through request will have you declaring the variable each time in each of the methods you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

There's a global property `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in the `System.Globalization` namespace that gets the culture for the current thread. This has existed as far back as [.NET Framework 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.0), and all the way through to the current version of [.NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1).