# Asp.Net Core get culture that support also unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a web application in asp.net core that uses MVC and RequestLocalization. Some of the controllers require the culture and I used solution from 
[Get the current culture in a controller asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289737/get-the-current-culture-in-a-controller-asp-net-core)

The application also has to have unit tests. But I can not mock the RequestCulture.

What is the solution to get the culture that also supports unit testing?

PS: I do not want to use the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or any solution that uses static classes or properties in the development code.

EDIT for Nkosi -  here is some code from memory:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
var mockFeatures = new Mock<IFeaturesCollection>();
var mockRequestFeature = new Mock<IRequestCultureFeature>();
var mockRequestCulture = new Mock<RequestCulture>();
mockRequestCulture.Setup(rc => rc.UICulture).Returns(mockCulture.Object);
// If I remember corectly this does not work
mockRequestFeature.Setup(rf => rf.RequestCulture).Returns(mockRequestCulture.Object); 
mockFeatures.Setuo(f => f.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>()).Returns(mockRequestFeature.Object);
mockContext.Setup(r => r.Features).Return(mockFeatures.Object);
```

Comment: Show how you are currently using/accessing request culture (controller or action under test) and what you have tried so far in trying to test it in a [mcve]. From there we could probably see how best we can help you find a solution.

Comment: You state the application uses RequestLocalization but have not shown how. Show an example of how one of the controllers require the culture and how it is accessed by the controller.

Comment: @Nkosi If you look at the link you will see the example on how I get the culture in a controller. As for the RequestLocalization you can look at the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization